# Unexpected http parameter read using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, httprequest

I'm not sure why am I getting such result.

If I load the following URL into a browser:

```
http://localhost:57845/app.ashx?n=update&url=some_url&logo=long_logo_name
```

where the app.ashx file contains this code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string strURL = context.Request.Params["url"];
}
```

My `strURL` variable becomes `some_url,/app.ashx`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `Params` property "gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx).

You should use `context.Request.QueryString["url"]` to get only "some_url".